# Replacing data in database

Tags: mysql, database, vba

I get a sheet of data that gets updated values daily, I am trying to write the updated data daily into the database to replace the data from the previous day. The database is Mysql. Also is it possible to use the replace function to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand your question, but to replace data you need a key for each row in your sheet.

Than you should

```
UPDATE <target_table> SET column1 = value1_from_sheet 
WHERE key = key_col_from_sheet
```

REPLACE is a string function in TSQL and you can not use it to replace rows in a table. It is useful to replace some chars inside a string.

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar(50);
SET @string = "someValue";

SELECT REPLACE(@string,'Va','XX') => 'someXXlue'
```